# Custom delimiter while exporting Google Cloud SQL to CSV

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

I've been successfully exporting GCloud SQL to CSV with its default delimiter ",". I want to import this CSV to Google Big Query and I've succeed to do this.

However, I'm experiencing a little problem. There's "," in some of my cell/field. It causes Big Query import process not working properly. For Example:

```
"Budi", "19", "Want to be hero, and knight"
```

My questions are:

- Is it possible to export Google Cloud SQL with custom delimiter e.g. "|"?
- If not, how to make above sample data to be imported in Google Big Query and become 3 field/cell?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to export Google Cloud SQL with custom delimiter e.g. "|"?

Yes it's, See the documentation page of BigQuery how to set load options provided in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#csv-options)

You will need to add `--field_delimiter = '|'` to your command

From the documentation:

> (Optional) The separator for fields in a CSV file. The separator can be any ISO-8859-1 single-byte character. To use a character in the range 128-255, you must encode the character as UTF8. BigQuery converts the string to ISO-8859-1 encoding, and uses the first byte of the encoded string to split the data in its raw, binary state. BigQuery also supports the escape sequence "\t" to specify a tab separator. The default value is a comma (`,`).

Comment: Hi Tamir, 

I used field_delimiter to import my custom CSV to Google Big Query. 

My question was how to export CSV from Google Cloud SQL with customer delimiter?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there's no way of setting a custom delimiter when exporting from CloudSQL to CSV. I attempted to introduce my own delimiter by formulating my select query like so:

```
select column_1||'|'||column_2 from foo
```

But this only results in CloudSQL escaping the whole result in the resulting CSV with double quotes. This also aligns with the documentation which states:

> Exporting in CSV format is equivalent to running the following SQL statement:

```
  SELECT <query> INTO OUTFILE ... CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
    ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/exporting